# View Flipper : Compile time or run time?

Tags: android, viewflipper

In view flipper if we specify 10 imageviews as the child,
are the image views loaded to the viewflipper at runtime ?
Or it is like at build time, the view flipper is inflated and the image views are populated in a array of sort and the array is used at run time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think imageviews are added at build time.

You can try this..

- Make 10 image view and make height of ViewFlipper to wrap content
- now fix the height of first 9 image view to say 50dip, and for 10th image view use length of say 100 dip
- You will notice that Vieflipper take the height of 100dip

That's is why, My perception is that it will load at build time. :)

Answer (score 1):

If u have already defined it in XML then its build time. I say this due to XML are converted into objects when view is made.

Comment: So , in app widgets it is always at build time ?